# Swift initializing image variables differently does not work

Tags: arrays, swift, initialization

I have a JSON file from which I two icon names: `normal` and `active`.
I use them to get the system icons, which I'd like to put inside an image array.
When I load them separately it works just fine:

```
struct loadData: Hashable, Codable {

    //load some data...

    private var normal_name: String
    private var active_name: String

    var normal_icon: Image {
        Image(systemName: normal_name)
    }
    var active_icon: Image {
        Image(systemName: normal_name)
    }
}
```

When I try to put the acquired images inside an array, it throws an error:

```
var icon: [Image] = [
    normal_icon,
    active_icon
]
```

Even if I try to load them directly, it still throws the same error:

```
var icon: [Image] = [
    Image(systemName: normal_name),
    Image(systemName: normal_name)
]
```

The error I get is this:

> Cannot use instance member 'normal_icon' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available

I know I can use a computed property to fix this issue, my question is:

Why am I allowed to initialize the string (`normal_name`) and then initialize the image (`normal_icon`) without getting an error, but when I do it inside the array it doesn't work?

Comment: Because `norrmal_icon` and `normal_name` are computed properties but `icon` is a stored property.

Comment: You could refactor icon to also be a computed property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show us the context where the code:

```
var icon: [Image] = [
  normal_icon,
  active_icon
]
```

lives, but are you doing this?:

```
struct loadData: Hashable, Codable {

    //load some data...

    private var normal_name: String
    private var active_name: String

    var icon: [Image] = [
      normal_icon,
      active_icon
    ]
}
```

If so, then you have to realize that `normal_icon` in the array declaration is really a reference to `self.normal_icon` so it is referencing `self` while trying to set up the field `icon`. But the fields of the object are initialized *before* `self` is available so you

> Cannot use instance member 'normal_icon' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available